# How to add an alert on Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function where:
After I click the link named `"hapus"`, the related data will be deleted and I want to have a popup alert to show that the data has been deleted.


*sorry for my bad english


*hapus technically means destroy

this the code:

```
public function hapus(Request $request, $id)
    {
        DB::table('kelompok')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: `with()`, `witherror()` these are some methods we can use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses) in your controller

```
 function hapus(Request $request, $id)
        {
            DB::table('kelompok')
            ->where('id', $id)
            ->delete();
            return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Deleted!');
        }
```

In your blade template, retrieve the `session` after being redirected from controller:

```
@if (session('alert'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('alert') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending @pbwned's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38764550/4485549),
you can also use javascript `alert box` in your blade view to display the flash session/message.

For example:

```
<script>
  var msg = '{{Session::get('alert')}}';
  var exist = '{{Session::has('alert')}}';
  if(exist){
    alert(msg);
  }
</script>
```

Hope it helps =)